# How can I make custom Google Maps markers with a custom dialog message

Tags: google-maps, dialog, marker

I need to create iframe Google Maps that I can embed on a site with a custom marker that would be the companies logo.
Once the marker is clicked, it should show a dialog with custom information instead of Google's default information with an address etc. I would like to modify it so it shows some information about the business. Just like the one that can be seen here: http://ekogaze.lv/kontakti.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating custom marker can be found [here](http://powerhut.co.uk/googlemaps/custom_markers.php).
Adding custom information can be done by updating values in the marker div.